# Updating multiple entries in a notion database with API

Tags: python, json, notion-api, notion

I have a notion database which I call with the API like so:

```py
url = f"https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/{NotionDB}/query"
payload = {"page_size": 200}
headers = { "Authorization": NotionKEY,
            "accept": "application/json",
            "Notion-Version": "2022-06-28",
            "content-type": "application/json"
        }
response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

This returns a `data['results']` with the following structure:

```py
[{'object': 'page',
  'id': 'ABC'
  ....
  'parent': {'type': 'database_id',
   'database_id': 'XXXXX'},
  'archived': False,
  'properties': {'Prop 1': {'id': '%40QKL',
   ....}},
  'url': 'https://www.notion.so/XYZ'},
 {'object': 'page',
  'id': 'CDE',
  'parent': {'type': 'database_id',
   'database_id': 'XXXXX'},
  'archived': False,
  'properties': {'Prop 1': {'id': '%40QKL',
    ..... }},
  'url': 'https://www.notion.so/ABCD'},
{'object': etc}, '{'object': etc}]
```

so, a list of objects, each of which seems to be a page.  My goal is to make some changes to the properties of those objects and then update the database.

I am able to do so looping over each individual page. After editing the list of jsons, I do:

```py
url = "https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/ID-OF-i_th-PAGE"
payload = {"properties": data['results'][i]['properties']}
headers = {
     "Authorization": NotionKEY,
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Notion-Version": "2022-06-28",
    "content-type": "application/json"
}
response = requests.patch(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

which works.  This however implies doing `N` API calls, if my list has `N` elements.  Is there a way to directly update the properties of the database elements in a single call?

Comment: you want to modify the keys or the values of the dictionaries ?

Comment: the values in the dictionaries.  The keys should stay.

Comment: you want to modify the nested dictionary of te key ```proprieties``` ? ```'properties': {'Prop 1': {'id': '%40QKL',
   ....}```?

Comment: I want to modify the values of a property.  An example of accessing such a value could be `data['results'][0]['properties']['Prop 1']['rich_text'][0]['text']['content']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Notion support this is not possible.  The feature has been requested but is not available on **Oct. 20th 2022**.